# Soldering very ESD sensitive component

Tags: soldering, esd

I need to solder terminals of a very ESD sensitive laser diode and the manufacturer recommends to use anti-static wristband which connects human body to earth.

During the soldering, I will also hold a soldering iron, a holder and a tweezer. Should all of these be earthed as well, or do metal tools not need to be earthed?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to work on an ESD safe workbench.  That is often just a regular worksurface with a grounded, conductive ESD mat on it.
- You need to use an ESD safe soldering iron.  It will be grounded to the earth ground of your electrical system through a resistor to drain off the electrostatic charge.
- You need to wear an ESD strap.  They usually have a conductive wrist band that connects to the earth ground of the electrical system through a (large value) resistor.
- Place the component in its ESD safe packaging on the ESD safe workbench before you open the package.  Only open such packages in an ESD safe place.
- Wear cotton or linen clothing while working at your ESD safe workbench.  No nylon, polyester, wool, or silk.
- Wear leather shoes with leather soles or ESD safe shoes.
- Since you will be grounded through your ESD strap, any metallic tools you use will automatically be grounded through you - you don't need to ground them separately.
- The "third hand" can be grounded.  It shouldn't build up any charge since it is on the ESD mat, but it can't hurt to clip a wire to it that goes to the ESD mat.  Otherwise, always touch the third hand with your own hand before putting the component in the clamps and touch the third hand with you hand before touch the component (in the clamps) with any tool.

If you will be doing a lot of work with such components, you may want to look into an ESD control air ionizer.  These blow a stream of ionized air to keep an electrostatic charge from building up around your work area.

Comment: I see I didn't think about a grounded mat. I think that sounds important, But my table(workbench) is wooden. How about the tweezers? Should they be grounded as well? https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSQ3ag60C6h5pTIpVy7FX7nDuxaax-WX6zeMfkjSZp9&s Or wearing antistatic grounded wrist is enough?

Comment: Wood doesn't usually build up much of a static charge, but it is hard to properly ground on. The mat is easier, and it works on any surface. If you are wearing an ESD strap, then you shouldn't need grounded tweezers.

Comment: @floppy380 Wooden surfaces are usually not a problem in my experience. Tweezers are usually conducting so no problem there, although there are "ESD tweezers" (which sounds like a scam in case the alternative is to use a steel one). All of this depends on what level of professionalism you are looking for - doing all of the bullets in this answer is what a professional contractor would do. If that's what you are, then that's what you have to do. If you are just some engineer looking to solder a prototype batch, then common sense will work and you can skip some of these.

Comment: (For example when soldering prototypes, I follow all of these except the wrist strap. I used to have a wooden surface but nowadays use an ESD mat - not because wood was bad but because I can now elbow my way into an electronics production line and use their workbenches.)

Comment: In my home hobby room, I don't usually use a wrist strap.  I have one but I don't generally bother to get it out and put it on.  I rely on the fact that I've spent years avoiding static discharge - I always touch the workbench before touching anything on it, I maintain contact with the workbench and its antistatic mat at all times while working, etc.  When I used to do this stuff everday (working on expensive equipment for a small company,) I did **not** rely on my habits.  A single "zap" could damage something that would then fail later.  I didn't take that gamble.  By the book, all the time.

Comment: How fanatic you are about ESD prevention depends on the cost of failure.  My hobby stuff?  If it breaks, I'm out a few bucks and have to order a replacment part.  The stuff I worked on professionally cost thousands of dollars per unit - you don't want to be killing those wantonly.  Worse, an unexpected failure could cause problems for the people using the equipment.  A single, unnoticed ESD "zap" can weaken a part such that it will fail months later while being used.

Comment: How expensive are your laser diodes?  What can happen (worst case) if one fails?  How hard is it to get a replacement?  If they are expensive, hard to get parts that go "bang" when damaged, then take all precautions you can.  If they are cheap "jelly bean" parts that you can get anywhere and simply don't work any more when damaged, then you can get away with few to little precautions.